# bootstrap multiselect dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am not able to get the alert for the dynamically added bootstrap select element

```
<html>

<head>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#days').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});

var i = 1;
$('#btnAddAnother').click(function(){
    var clone_multiselect = $("#days").clone();
    clone_multiselect.attr('id', 'days' + i);
    clone_multiselect.appendTo(".multiselect_container");

    $(clone_multiselect).multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

    i++;
});

$('#btnGetSelected').click(function() {
    $('.results').empty();
    $('select.multiselect').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var selected_option_selector = '#' + id + ' option:selected';
        var result_str = '<b>' + id + '</b>: ';

        $(selected_option_selector).each(function(){
            result_str += $(this).text() + ' - ' + $(this).val() + ', ';
        });

        result_str = result_str.substring(0, result_str.length - 2);
        result_str += '<br />';
        $('.results').append(result_str);
    });




});

 $(document.body).on("click","select.multiselect",function(){
    alert("hello");
  });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="multiselect_container">
    <select id="days" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">thursday</option>
      <option value="2">sunday</option>
      <option value="3">monday</option>
      <option value="4">tuesday</option>
      <option value="5">friday</option>
    </select>
</div>

<br />
<button id="btnGetSelected" class="btn btn-primary">Get Selected</button>
<button id="btnAddAnother" class="btn btn-primary">+ Add Another Set OF Hourse</button>

<div class="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should register your event **after** you created your element.
You should put your event listener that display the alert into the event listener that create your select element, after the creation.

I hope it helped !

EDIT : here is the code I made, i change "click" event by "change" because the bootstrap multiselect seems to override the click event. The alert shows up when you click on an option, I don't know if it's what you want.

```
var i = 1;
$('#btnAddAnother').on('click', function(){

  var clone_multiselect = $("#days").clone();
  clone_multiselect.attr('id', 'days' + i);
  clone_multiselect.appendTo(".multiselect_container");

  $(clone_multiselect).multiselect({
      includeSelectAllOption: true
  });

  $(clone_multiselect).on("change",function(){
    alert("hello");
}); 

  i++;
});

$('#btnGetSelected').click(function() {
  $('.results').empty();
  $('select.multiselect').each(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var selected_option_selector = '#' + id + ' option:selected';
      var result_str = '<b>' + id + '</b>: ';

      $(selected_option_selector).each(function(){
          result_str += $(this).text() + ' - ' + $(this).val() + ', ';
      });

      result_str = result_str.substring(0, result_str.length - 2);
      result_str += '<br />';
      $('.results').append(result_str);
  });

});
```

Comment: But that is whyJQuery on is used .

Comment: I used .on on a project with dynamicaly added element, and i got the same issue. So i register the event after inserting the element in the DOM. And it fixed the issue

Comment: i make a fiddle ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

Be sure you are using the appropriate classes **.custom-select**

```
<select class="custom-select">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**Answer 2**

If you absolutely must, another solution would be to create a change listener, listen for changes, then initialize the [multi-select](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#select-menu).

```
$('#days').change(function(){
  $(clone_multiselect).multiselect({includeSelectAllOption: true});
});
```